# Escaping HTML in comments and answers

Tags: discussion, support, user-experience, formatting

How do we escape HTML content in answers and comments? I am sure this question was covered somewhere, but I am not able to find it; I have searched in help section, but eventually gave up.

A concrete example: in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49386625/6393636), I tried to give an answer with a demo on HTML injection. The HTML there is not in a code block (it would be escaped in that case), but in the URL. How can I escape that?
The goal there was:
localhost:8080/xss-reflected?param=(Inject some Html encoded code here)

Comment: Using inline code formatting for the URL seems good enough.

Comment: @duplode Sorry but I don't see it, while writing an answer I only see buttons for Bold, Italic, Hyperlink, blockquote, code, image, Js/css snippet, lists, heading, horizontal rule .. where is that "inline code formatting" ?

Comment: Use backticks: \`meta.stackoverflow.com\` will be displayed as `meta.stackoverflow.com`. All the buttons in the editor toolbar do is inserting Markdown syntax, which is plain text that you can type normally. The "?" button in the editor gives a quick overview of that; see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information.

Comment: I knew about the backtick trick, but I was not happy with that, instead I want to show a raw h2 without any special styling, for example, how did you escaped your backtick from your last comment?

Comment: Backslashes escape Markdown syntax (\\`foobar\\` becomes \`foobar\`, \\*foobar\\* becomes \*foobar\*, etc.), but not HTML tags. I believe the best option for that are HTML entities (&lt;h2&gt; becomes <h2>, etc -- note that that isn't necessary in comments, as they don't accept raw HTML formatting).

Comment: (Incidentally, I feel my comment above would be easier to read if I had used inline code formatting for the strings to the left of each "becomes". You might want to consider whether the same applies to your URLs.)

Comment: @duplode thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: I have consolidated my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest solution is to use inline code formatting for your URLs. `` `https:\\meta.stackoverflow.com` `` will be displayed as `https:\\meta.stackoverflow.com`. While URLs are not code, they are sufficiently code-like to justify using code formatting. (See also [*When should code formatting be used for non-code text?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/2751851) and [this answer to *Can we have proper formatting for console output?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298884/2751851) for further discussion of this point.)

If you don't want to use inline code formatting, Markdown syntax can be escaped with backslashes (e.g. `\*foobar\*` becomes *foobar*), and HTML tags can be rendered by using HTML entities (e.g. `&lt;h2&gt;` becomes <h2>). The latter trick is not necessary in comments, as they don't accept raw HTML formatting.

P.S.: To see how to include backticks within inline code, as I did in the first paragraph, or how to display &lt;h2&gt; within text which is not formatted as code, have a look at the source of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to format the URL with the injected HTML as inline code. It is not semantically incorrect to do so, is very easy to do (the Markdown formatter handles all the special character encoding for you so you don't have to do it yourself), and is universally understood by all readers.

URLs left unformatted, while doing so is not wrong either, tend to be misconstrued by readers as URLs that are intended to be clicked anyway, so by formatting them as inline code you're doing yourself and everyone multiple favors.