# How do I edit a post to distinguish interspersed code and console output clearly?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, markdown

I have a question along related lines, but not identical, to [Can we have proper formatting for console output?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298882/)  and [Should I prefix example Python code with ">>>" to indicate running in the interpreter?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310839) .  My question is specifically about interspersing code and its console output, in a way that could generalize to longer code segments.

### Background

Often I want to show both console input and output in a Stack Overflow question or answer. I'm looking for a markdown strategy or convention that is easy to type, clear and unambiguous.

Here's a Python example. Let's say that Alice does it this way:

```
>>> a = first_stage()
>>> print(a)
1.234
>>> b = next_stage(a)
```

Hopefully it's obvious that the `>>>` is the Python prompt, that anything following it is what you're supposed to type *at* the Python prompt, and that the lines without `>>>` are what you should consequently see as console output. It's often useful to show intermediate outputs like this, to help in understanding the flow of a question or answer.  This convention works OK but of course it makes it annoying to copy, paste and try the code (the `>>>` have to be deleted by hand), and sometimes it's helpful to intersperse console output in fairly long pieces of code rather than just a few short test lines, which is also why the approach in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310915/ isn't always ideal

Here are some more ideas. Bob does it like this:

```
a = first_stage()
print(a)
# 1.234
```

and Charlie does it like this:

```
a = first_stage()
print(a)  # 1.234
```

Now you can copy-paste the code, but clearly there are still potential drawbacks: in Bob's version, you just have to hope that the reader understands that the `#` wasn't literally printed; in Charlie's, you hope they understand that the comment is console output and not a comment *about* the command that produced it, and you also can't handle multi-line output. And so on.  Nothing I've tried is quite satisfactory under a wide range of circumstances.

### My Questions

Are there good existing conventions?  Or existing interface functionality or markdown tricks that help do this without too much effort? I could imagine a two-column table with code left and output right, but I believe SO markdown doesn't allow tables and can only imagine unwieldy syntax for them relative to what I'm looking for.

If not (and to save this question from being considered an entirely opinion-based comparison of possible styles):  should SO implement a canonical solution for this broadly-applicable feature?

Comment: I think everything you showed is just fine.  I personally don't have much REPL assistance and need to use a separate code-block to show output, that works too when your code is more substantial.

Comment: What I see people doing pretty often is to just label their output as output. It's a little wordier but you don't have to worry about someone being confused about what it is.

Comment: It is not uncommon to want to highlight some portion(s) of the code that are interesting, and the basic Markdown doesn't allow for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use both of the methods you showed, especially the prompt convention for Python. But I might prefer to go for full explicitness:

```
a = 0.1000
print(a)
# Prints: 0.1
```

For longer output, the multi-line equivalent:

```
print(list(range(100)))
# Prints:
# [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]
```

Comment: It's deceptively simple/obvious but I probably like the `# Prints:\n# ...` approach best of all the suggestions here. Firstly, including that verb lets the comment explicitly play the semantic role of a code comment, at the same time as showing the output. Secondly, that  prefix line clearly establishes the convention that whatever follows will be prefixed with `# ` (i.e. that these two characters are not part of the output).   The only thing that output-as-comment-lines approaches make difficult is copy-pasting the output itself (if that's ever desirable).

Comment: @jez, thanks. If the output is more than one line and needs to be copy-pastable, then embedding it in a separate display block is the way to go. (If it's one line it's easy enough to start the selection after the comment symbol :-))

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes, I use `<pre>` for output:

```
    a = first_stage()
    print(a)
<pre>
1.234
</pre>
    b = next_stage(a)
```

resulting in:

```py
a = first_stage()
print(a)
```

```
1.234
```

```
b = next_stage(a)
```

But this is more useful for larger blocks, where I actually want do disable syntax highlighting, and where the presence or absence of syntax highlighting makes it obvious what is code and what is output.

---

For smaller outputs, it might be a better idea to format them as quotes:

```
    a = first_stage()
    print(a)

> 1.234

    b = next_stage(a)
```

resulting in:

```py
a = first_stage()
print(a)
```

> 1.234

```
b = next_stage(a)
```

This will break the formatting of the console output, if it relies on using a monospace font. (And code-inside-quote is possible, but looks silly.)

Comment: You can also use normal code blocks and just toss an unindented HTML comment (`<!-- -->`) between the sections you want to separate.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use pre-tags. If you want no code-highlight, use `<!-- language: lang-none -->`.

Comment: That's more typing …

Comment: @CL. not if you master the art of copy&paste.

Comment: The main reason why I don't like this convention is that if I want to run the code myself I can't simply copy/paste it into my editor and run it, as the output will be interpreted as code and potentially cause errors. This is why I always comment out output.

Comment: Markdown has its own comments - `<% %>` - even short than HTML ones.

Answer (score 8):

## Document the block like it is source code

The way I normally handle this is all example output/explanations are included as comments (as if I was documenting the actual source code) so that the entire block can be copy-paste-execute.

```
a = first_stage()
print(a) 
#1.234
b = next_stage(a)
```

This way, anyone who can read the code can tell what is code and what isn't, and the person copy-pasting doesn't have to purge the explanations if they don't want to. This is also a strategy that works across all languages, and usually how people are used to seeing documentation. And since comments are informal, you can be as simple or detailed as you like. Since the comment part is obvious, and the context of a print is obvious, no one should have any problem telling `1.1234` is the output if it's in a comment followed by or is on the same line as a print.

Comment: The only problem I have with this is the comment gets greyed out for some languages (e.g. Python), to the extent that spotting nuances in the output is... tedious, if not painful.

Comment: @jpp That would be a SE CSS issue, that I'm surprised wasn't something that got fixed immediately. Though if it is a problem for the reader, they can easily "override" that CSS by highlighting the text. (specifically the SE "com" css class).

Comment: This is already pretty much the convention in the R tag, although usually with a space after the octo for readability, and I think it works rather well. [Eg.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430388/confidence-interval-for-normal-distribution-r)

Answer (score 2):

## Depends on the intent of the post and context

**REPL session** - If you are literally showing a REPL session, display it that way with a nice label.  `<pre>` tag works well here

**Python (or description of environment):**

```
>>> a = 2 + 2
4
```

**Code** - If you want to emphasize the `code` or need help debugging, then write it as code with comments:

```
a = first_stage()
print(a) # should print 1.234
```

**Code output** -
If you want to emphasize the output from running code, but still show the code, separate blocks work well:

```
a = first_stage()
print(a)
```

Prints:

> 1.234

Answer (score 2):

When the intent of the answer is to say which user input to provide during an interactive session, I'll use bold text within the `<pre>` block to highlight that input.

```
<pre>
(gdb) <b>b func</b>
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400580: file s2.c, line 19.
(gdb) <b>set $funcbp = $bpnum</b>
(gdb) <b>commands</b>
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
><b># We don't want to a watchpoint more than once</b>
><b># if func is called more than once,</b>
><b># so we disable the func breakpoint on first use.</b>
><b>disable $funcbp</b>
><b>watch -l x if $_caller_is("func", 0)</b>
><b>commands</b>
 ><b>continue</b>
 ><b>end</b>
><b>continue</b>
><b>end</b>
(gdb) <b>r</b>
Starting program: /home/mp/s2
</pre>
```

```
(gdb) b func
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400580: file s2.c, line 19.
(gdb) set $funcbp = $bpnum
(gdb) commands
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
># We don't want to set a watchpoint more than once
># if func is called more than once,
># so we disable the func breakpoint on first use.
>disable $funcbp
>watch -l x if $_caller_is("func", 0)
>commands
 >continue
 >end
>continue
>end
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/mp/s2
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a hypothetical feature proposal that would present code and output interspersed (but clearly visually demarcated) by default, with the option to view either the code alone, or the output alone, allowing either to be copy-pasted and used without modification.

It would require a new feature in the Markdown interpreter, which could be as simple as:

```
    a = first_stage()
    print(a)
<!-- output -->
    1.234
<!-- code -->
    b = second_stage(a)
<!-- output -->
    This gets printed as a side-effect
    of second_stage()
```

This could be rendered with the dynamic ability to switch between code, output, and a mixture of both.  It might look something like the output of this snippet (disclaimer: I have no doubt that you, the SO developers, and possibly the average labrador would likely do a better job of the actual html/js/css than I have done here - the point I'm trying to illustrate is really the output effect):

```js
function display(displayCode, displayOutput)
{
  var blocks = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");
  for(var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++)
  {
    if(blocks[i].classList.contains("code")) blocks[i].style["display"] = (displayCode   ? "block" : "none" );
    if(blocks[i].classList.contains("output"))
    {
      var style = blocks[i].style;
      style["display"] = (displayOutput ? "block" : "none");
      style["margin-left"] = (displayCode ? "2em" : "0");
      style["background-color"] = (displayCode ? "#dfe0f1" : "#eff0f1");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.mixedCodeBlock {
  margin-bottom:1em;
  padding:5px;
  padding-bottom:20px !ie7;
  width:auto;
  width:650px !ie7;
  max-height:600px;
  overflow:auto;
  font-family:Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  background-color:#eff0f1;
}
.output {
  margin-left:2em;
  background-color:#dfe0f1;
}

.selector {
  padding-right: 2em;
  font-size:13px;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 1em;">
  <span class="selector" onClick="display(1,1);">Mixed</span>
  <span class="selector" onClick="display(1,0);">Code Only</span>
  <span class="selector" onClick="display(0,1);">Output Only</span>
</div>
<div class="mixedCodeBlock">
<pre class="code">
a = first_stage()
print(a)
</pre>
<pre class="output">
1.234
</pre>
<pre class="code">
b = second_stage(a)
</pre>
<pre class="output">
This gets printed as a side-effect
of second_stage()
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Event attributes are the devil. Also, why in the world would you use `Display = function` at all? Also, why do you use a capital first letter for an identifier that does not identify a constructor? Also, why no indentation in the HTML, and such odd use of whitespace in the JavaScript?

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm really looking for feedback about the idea, not to be distracted by the nitty-gritty of the quick and dirty js code I used to illustrate it.  In both cases the answer is "I hardly ever use javascript and some of my knowledge may be up to 15 years out of date".

Comment: Oh, well in that case I think this would be a bad idea.